# Android Realm Project Structure

Tags: android, mvvm, realm, helper

I started working in a project that already had Realm and the MVVM structure on it. As of now, all Realm methods are static and inside a RealmHelper class, except for some methods that are in the ViewModel classes of it's respective Activity. But RealmHelper class is starting to get bigger and bigger and kinda messy. I wanted to know what are your suggestions to rearrange my methods and classes when using Realm.

Comment: you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31560557/2413303 and decide on it

Comment: Thank you, I'll took a look and seems interesting

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine if you want to keep the `RealmHelper` class which manages all of the methods that your app can access. You may want to try to convert the methods to one liners that are being directed to another class internally.

So the structure might look something like this:

co.your.app.realmhelper

- RealmHelper [public]
- WriterHelper [Package Private]
- ReaderHelper [Package Private]

So all of your logic is actually happening within the package private classes but the rest of your app would interface with the RealmHelper. The RealmHelper would just manage the instances of the package private classes and determine which methods should be invoked for those classes.

Your other option is to get rid of the RealmHelper in favor of smaller classes. Without knowing what your RealmHelper is actually doing it's difficult to give additional advice.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Today RealmHelper it's not that big, but it has  all kinds of methods (Readers and Writers and other checks) on it for every Model, it looks messy. I wanted to create a pattern. Your idea of a WriterHelper and ReaderHelper sounds really good.

Comment: So when I did a project in Realm I basically had helpers for each model I was representing within Realm which shared a base implementation.

So something like `AbstractDao` and then that would have base implementations for the CRUD operations. Then each model would have their own Dao which could add additional operations. This could be another useful route for you to explore, unfortunately I don't have an open source solution to share at this time.

Comment: The one I linked above would be a very similar pattern, except I called `Dao` as `repository`.

Comment: There's another issue with RealmHelper that I came up with. I used realm.where() to bring all contents from DB. On my fragment I have a list of these objects and when the user touches on the item, it should set a property "checked" true. But when it does, the app crashes with "Changing Realm data can only be done from inside a transaction" exception. So I used copyFromRealm() to overcome this. 
So using a helper is possible to keep the transaction open to update database items in UI?

Comment: If item needs to be changed and persisted with said change then i do not know why you would make an unmanaged copy instead of executing an asynchronous transaction and update UI via `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`'s auto-update

Comment: Because item can't be persisted. I have a list of items which I bring back from an API. And I need to save it on Realm cause I need to work with this original data evertime. User will select from this content list what he desires and I'll save it too, but without changing the original data, since he has to choose from it everytime. (And I have to keep it all offline)